# Maximum Sum of Two Elements in a Circular Array

Tags: arrays, sum, max, distance

Suppose you are given N non-negative numbers (stored in an array) that represent points in a circle. We need to find two elements, such that the sum of these two elements **plus** the distance they have in the circle is maximum.

Example:
Suppose the array is: A = { 0, 4, 2, 3, 1 }
Then the circular configuration is:

```
           0
          ...
        .'   '.
      .'       '.
    1|           '|4
     \            /
      \          /
       \        /
        \______/
        3      2
```

In this example, the maximum sum of two elements plus its distance
is: 4 + (1 + 1 + 1) + 3 = 10, where the parentheses is the intermediate distances.

Why?
Because we go from 4 to 3 counter-clockwise.

Relevant thoughts:

1. A bruteforce approach is O(n^2).
2. I believe it is possible to solve it in O(n Log n)
3. For any two elements in the array, we choose the greatest distance in the circle. That means that this distance is at least half the length of the circle. Thus, at least two edges( of the "diameter" ) of the circle will always be part of the maximum sum we are asking for.

Comment: Please edit .... Also why distance between 4 and 3 is 3 and not 2?

Comment: Sorry, it is the first time i am posting. I believe it is ok now

Comment: Pls. note that this is not a 'we volunteer to do your homework'-site, but rather a 'show me where your program failed and I'll help'-site, and for theoretical issues there are better sites in the network...

Comment: I just need a hint or some idea to get this started.